# Transition from a ModalView to a PushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I will make an simple example. We first have a FirstViewController embedded in a NavigationController which is also embedded in a TabBarController. In the FirstViewController I do a simple expansion transition of a UIImage using a full screen modal transition (presentViewController: animated:) where the navigationbar and the tabbar are not there anymore. In this SecondViewController, I have a tableView and I'd like to tap on a row to present/push another ThirdViewController which will have the tabbar and navigation which were on the FirstViewController.

Maybe this is not a modal transition I need to do to achieve what I want. *Facebook* app does something similar when you try to see an image in your timeline. In the full screen image, you can display the profile with a push-like transition.

If anyone can help me, thanks in advance.